# How to control the row width and height within a SQL script with html tags?

Tags: html, sql, image, oracle, tags

This is purely just a cosmetic problem.  Whenever I try to include html tags in my scripts, the output screen on oracle sql developer (blank worksheet) shows what would show on a website (ex: just the image), but then also includes a whole lot of white space to the right within the cell.  I think it's basically showing the amount of space it would take to show the full html tag, if it were visible.

Here is an example script:

```
SELECT '<HTML><img src="http://www.bbcshop.com/content/ebiz/bbc/invt/sc192/dw_matt_smtih_cut_out_300.jpg"></HTML>' as MoreFunStuff FROM dual
```

Is there a way to:

a) eliminate all of the white space to the right, and just show the image at its correct width (either by telling it to use the picture dimension, or specifying manually)

and

b) increase the row height to accomodate the image, again, either using the original image's dimension, or specifying it manually

and here's the kicker:

Is there a way to do this all within the script, so it will show correctly no matter who runs the script (i.e. not a user preference setting)?

Comment: what are you using the to run the script, or in other words, what application is providing the 'output screen' ?

Comment: oracle sql developer, a blank worksheet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you run your script using F5, you'll get script output. The grid launches a mini-web browser for each cell it encounters an html tag in the first 6 chars...you could also prefix the row with 6 or more spaces or hidden characters to interrupt the rendering of the actual HTML

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about prefixing the row with 6 or more spaces?  Can you show me what you mean in a script?

Comment: select '________' || html_col from table... or just run as normal with F5 as there's no fancy HTML rendering there.